# What is the opposite of HTMLDialogElement.showModal()?

Tags: javascript, dialog, html-5.2

Using the HTML 5.2 native [`<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) element I can open the dialog using Javascript.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const dialog = document.getElementsByTagName('dialog')[0];
  dialog.showModal();
});
```

How can I use Javascript to close the dialog?

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal) suggests `.close()` - read it and see if I'm right

Comment: The example on the [`showModal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal) page clearly shows using `.close()` to close it. What's the problem?

Comment: The downside to using those methods is the CSS pseudo-element ::backdrop won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The dialog can be opened, and closed using the `open()` and `close()` methods. The downside to using these methods is the CSS pseudo-element `::backdrop` won't work.

```
<button id="open">Open Dialog</button>
<button id="close">Close Dialog</button>

<dialog id="dialog">
  <h2>Dialog Title</h2>
  <p>Dialog content and other stuff will go here</p>
</dialog>

<script>
const dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");

document.getElementById("open").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.show();
});

document.getElementById("close").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.close();
});
</script>
```